# 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ffmpeg_player'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This post ([how do i make my discord.py bot play mp3 in voice channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604339/how-do-i-make-my-discord-py-bot-play-mp3-in-voice-channel)) recommend this piece of code :

```
player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('vuvuzela.mp3', after=lambda: print('done'))
```

Here's my line :

```
self.player = await self.vc.create_ffmpeg_player('song.mp3')
```

But after doing the same thing, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lam/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 41, in on_message
    self.player = await self.vc.create_ffmpeg_player('song.mp3')
AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ffmpeg_player'
```

Did they change the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats my example, thought that looked familiar. That example was written using discord.py version 0.16.12. So if you are using the discord.py rewrite then that code wont work. Here is a link to the docs where they explain the changes to voice https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/migrating.html#voice-changes That very first example is what youre looking for.