# YDL is not working in my simple discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

this is the rewrite version of discord py and im having this problem

i've tried to look for a solution for 3 days

````
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get
import youtube_dl


@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'P'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player[server.id]

client.run(token)`


'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation about [VoiceClient](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_client#discord.VoiceClient). You will see there is no function `create_ytdl_player(url)`. If we look further and take a look at the [changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#voice-changes) we will see that this function has been removed.

But it also notes the following:

> create_ffmpeg_player/create_stream_player/create_ytdl_player have all been removed.
>
> The goal is to create AudioSource instead.

There are a few examples in the change. But you will need to use the [play](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_client#discord.VoiceClient.play) function in combination with an audiosource. If you want to read more on how to use it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330774/12493001) is a solution on how to play a mp3.