# Asyncio - wait until a line of code executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have the following block of code:

```
async def all():
    audios = []
    ...
    for file in audios:
        player = voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", source=file))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

The line `player=...` is supposed to play an audio on a discord server. The problem with this code is that the line `await asyncio.sleep(1)` doesn't wait until `player` is done playing, but instead it will start as soon as `player` is called instead, that will make the loop go forward and call `player` another time while `player` is already running from the previous instance and so on. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `player`? If it's an awaitable, you can just `await` it before you `sleep`. If it has some other method to get an awaitable for when it completes, call that and `await` it. If it's not `asyncio` friendly, but has some blocking method to wait until it's complete, [run that method in an executor with `run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) and `await` the result of that call (`run_in_executor` used so you don't block the event loop while blocking on the method).

Comment: Yes, voice.play should be an awaitable, but when i try to await it i get the following error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Than it's not an awaitable; it returns `None`. You'll need to check the docs for how you're supposed to handle this; it's clearly not as simple as `await`ing the result when the result isn't an awaitable. I'm not clear on what API `voice.play` comes from, so it's hard to help more.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, it's not a coroutine, so i need to find some other way. I just read that voice.play has an after parameter that can be executed when the audio is done playing, maybe it can be helpful

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53604339/364696); looks like at least some APIs return a real object with `.start()` and `.is_done()` methods; a simple polling loop with `.is_done()` and `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` or whatever would get you close enough to what you want, and you'd just add a further `await asyncio.sleep(1.)` after the loop to make it a little over a second from end of one playback to continuing loop.

Comment: Yeah! Using .is_done() seems like a good way to go! Thanks!

Comment: Are you just wanting to play some audio files sequentially with a 1s delay in between each one? I'm not sure you want/need `asyncio` for this. Just replace `asyncio.sleep(1)` with `time.sleep(1)`. Your problem is that the loop continues with the next `file` as its waiting for the sleep to finish.